# How to offset a Range<T> in Swift?

Tags: swift

Imagine we have an arbitrary `Range<T>` and we want to create a new range with `startIndex` and `endIndex` advanced by 50 units.

My first thought was to do this:

```
let startIndex = advance(range.startIndex, 50)
let endIndex = advance(range.endIndex, 50)
var newRange = startIndex..<endIndex
```

But this gives "fatal error: can not increment endIndex". (Well, it does with `Range<String.Index>`. I haven't tried it with other generic parameters.) I've tried quite a few permutations of this, including assigning `range.startIndex` and `range.endIndex` to new variables, etc. Nothing works.

Let me stress that I'm looking for a solution that works with *any* `T`. GoZoner gave an answer below that I haven't tried with `Int`, but I wouldn't be surprised if it worked. However, no permutation of it I tried will work when `T` is `String.Index`

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s a second version of `advance` that takes a maximum index not to go beyond:

```
let s = "Hello, I must be going."
let range = s.startIndex..<s.endIndex

let startIndex = advance(range.startIndex, 50, s.endIndex)
let endIndex = advance(range.endIndex, 50, s.endIndex)
var newRange = startIndex..<endIndex

if newRange.isEmpty {
    println("new range out of bounds")
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I *do* want to go beyond that maximum index.

Comment: To what goal?  String indices are, under the hood, pointers to memory (with bounds checks to assert if you go beyond the end, unless you compile with the unchecked optimizer).  That’s why `"hello".endIndex.successor()
` gives you a runtime assertion.  You can’t do this generically with non-integer indices because the generic rule for indices is you can’t advance them past the end.  It just happens to work for array indices due to that specific implementation.

Comment: The goal is hard to explain, but involves a tokenizer library I'm writing. You can imagine it as a means to convert between "coordinate systems" of two strings, one of which is a substring of another at an arbitrary position. In many operations, it's convenient to work in ranges of the substring, but then I need to convert it back to a range in the "superstring". I already have a way to do this, but this question arose as a curiosity while trying a naive implementation.

Comment: In other words, let's say I have the string 'Hello, I must be going.' My tokenizer is at position `6` in that string, so the remaining string is "I must be going." I have a token recognizer that matches "I". The range of that in the substring is of course '{0, 1}'. Now I want to take that range and convert it to the equivalent range in the superstring '{6,7}'. This isn't hard to do, but my first implementation attempt led me to this question.

Comment: Ah I’ve got you – maybe something like getting the “width” of the subrange via `countElements(subrange)` (which would be of type `String.Distance` - in this case {0,1} would be 1), then if you have the original start of that subrange in terms of the superstring, you could advance that by the distance to give you the range in terms of the superstring (so you have 6, add distance to give 7 to give you {6,7}).  If you want to offset from the start of the supplied substring too, you’d have to do `distance(substring.startIndex, subrange.startIndex)` to generate another distance.

Comment: Yep, I ended up using a solution similar to what you described.

Comment: For posterity, here is my little (as yet unfinished and certainly unpolished) tokenizer library for Swift, [Betokened](https://github.com/Prosumma/betokened).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  1> var r1 = 1..<50
  r1: Range<Int> = 1..<50

  2> var r2 = (r1.startIndex+50)..<(r1.endIndex+50)
  r2: Range<Int> = 51..<100
```

Comment: While this may work with `Int`, it doesn't work with `String.Index`, unfortunately. I'm looking for a solution general enough to work with any `T`, but especially `String.Index`.